# Calculo de SLA no PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Quero calcular o tempo entre a data de registro até agora(current_timestamp). Ex: Se o registro foi 2019-03-01 09:11:17 e agora é 2019-03-01 09:46:17 então deverá me retornar 00:35:00 minutos, certo? Só que este tempo deverá parar de contar depois das 18:00 e só retornar depois das 08:00 no dia seguinte. Também não deverá contar nos sábados, domingos e nem em feriados.

Comment: para a hora seria só isso `and extract(hour from data) between 8 and 18`, não ? quanto aos sábados, domingos e feriados, melhor usar as datas em que há atendimento, dificilmente passa um dia com 0 atendimentos... de qlqr forma a pergunta não está muito clara... procure no [tour] as instruções de como elaborar uma pergunta.

Comment: Creio que para tratar eventuais feriados, pontos facultativos e similares (nacionais, estaduais ou municipais), será necessário criar uma tabela com tais datas.

Answer (score 0):

Não sei se entendi muito bem, mas você quer saber os registros que estão no horário comercial?

Se sim a solução comentada anteriormente resolve. Abaixo segue um exemplo conforme a resposta anterior, e também a complemento com a função isodow, que serve para saber qual dia da semana uma determinada data está. Segue exemplo de consulta de segunda a sexta das 8 a 18 horas:

```
create table teste (
    datahora timestamp
);

Insert into teste values (current_timestamp);
Insert into teste values (current_timestamp + interval '1' day);
Insert into teste values (current_timestamp + interval '2' day);
Insert into teste values (current_timestamp + interval '3' day);
Insert into teste values (current_timestamp + interval '4' day);

select* from teste where (extract(hour from datahora) between 8 and 18) and (extract(isodow from datahora) between 1 and 5);
```

Complementando a sua necessidade, de somar o SLA do registro datahora mas somente das 8 as 18 horas dos dias de semana, montei uma query com a clausula WITH e WITH RECURSIVE, mas também poderia ter sido utilizada uma TEMP TABLE. Vale a pena pesquisar um pouco sobre ela e sobre CTE. Segue exemplo:

```
Insert into teste values (current_timestamp + interval '-10' day);
Insert into teste values (current_timestamp + interval '-12' day);
Insert into teste values (current_timestamp + interval '-15' day);

with recursive sla_dias_anteriores (datahora_original, datahora_inicial, datahora_final, diferenca_horas) as (
    select date_trunc('sec', datahora) as datahora_original, date_trunc('sec', datahora) as datahora_inicial, (date_trunc('day', datahora) +  interval '18' hour) as datahora_final, ((date_trunc('day', datahora) +  interval '18' hour) - date_trunc('sec', datahora)) as diferenca_horas from teste where (extract(hour from datahora) between 8 and 18) and (extract(isodow from datahora) between 1 and 5)
    union
    select datahora_original, 
    h.datahora_inicial as datahora_inicial,
    h.datahora_final as datahora_final, 
    ( h.datahora_final -  h.datahora_inicial) as diferenca_horas from sla_dias_anteriores as s
    , lateral (select (date_trunc('day', datahora_inicial) +  interval '1' day + interval '8' hour) as datahora_inicial, (date_trunc('day', datahora_final) +  interval '1' day + interval '18' hour) as datahora_final) as h
    where s.datahora_final <= current_timestamp
),
sla_dia_atual (datahora_original, datahora_inicial, datahora_final, diferenca_horas) as (
    select date_trunc('sec', datahora) as datahora_original, h.datahora_inicial as datahora_inicial, h.datahora_final as datahora_final, (h.datahora_final - h.datahora_inicial) as diferenca_horas
    from teste,
    lateral (select (date_trunc('day', current_timestamp::timestamp) +  interval '8' hour) as datahora_inicial, (date_trunc('sec', current_timestamp::timestamp)) as datahora_final) as h
    where (extract(hour from datahora) between 8 and 18) and (extract(isodow from datahora) between 1 and 5)
)
select q.datahora_original, sum (q.diferenca_horas) as soma_sla from (
    select * from sla_dias_anteriores where datahora_final <= current_timestamp 
    union 
    select * from sla_dia_atual) as q group by q.datahora_original;
```